# Convert blob to WAV file without loosing data or compressing

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, blob, wav

I am working on recording speeches and converting them to downloadable WAV files. I am using Angular6 and MediaRecorder. Firstly I obtain the blob and from the blob, I get the .wav file. The problem is that the WAV file (which can be played and sounds good) loss much of its properties during the process and is not a valid WAV. It keeps being a WebM file. For further processing, I need really valid and high-quality WAV files. In the end, I get files of ~20KB, instead of bigger files of ~300KB.

My code looks like this:

```
//convert Blob to File. Pass the blob and the file title as arguments
var blobToFile = (theBlob: Blob, fileName:string): File => {
  var b: any = theBlob;
  //Add properties to the blob
  b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
  b.name = fileName;
  return <File>theBlob;
}

var browser = <any>navigator;  
var headers = new Headers();  
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var chunks =[];
var constraints = { audio: true, video: false }; 

var promisifiedOldGUM = function(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  var getUserMedia = (browser.getUserMedia || browser.webkitGetUserMedia || browser.mozGetUserMedia || browser.msGetUserMedia);

  // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error to keep a consistent interface
  if(!getUserMedia) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
  }

  // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
  return new Promise(function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    getUserMedia.call(browser, constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
  });

}
if (browser.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  browser.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => { 
  this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);        

this.mediaRecorder.onstop  = function(){
        var last_bit= chunks[chunks.length-1];
        var blob = new Blob([last_bit], { 'type' : 'audio/wav' });
        var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        //convert Blob to file 
        var file = blobToFile(blob, "my-recording.wav"); 

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = audioURL;
        link.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
        link.innerHTML = "download file";
        document.body.appendChild(link);  
};
```

And the MediaRecorder setup in `typings.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
declare class MediaRecorder extends EventTarget {

// readonly mimeType: string;
readonly MimeType: 'audio/x-wav';  // 'audio/vnd.wav';
readonly state: 'inactive' | 'recording' | 'paused';
readonly stream: MediaStream;
ignoreMutedMedia: boolean;
videoBitsPerSecond: number;
audioBitsPerSecond: 16000//number;

ondataavailable: (event : MediaRecorderDataAvailableEvent) => void;
onerror: (event: MediaRecorderErrorEvent) => void;
onpause: () => void;
onresume: () => void;
onstart: () => void;
onstop: () => void;

constructor(stream: MediaStream);

start();

stop();

resume();

pause();

isTypeSupported(type: string): boolean;

requestData();


addEventListener<K extends keyof MediaRecorderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaStream, ev: MediaRecorderEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

removeEventListener<K extends keyof MediaRecorderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MediaStream, ev: MediaRecorderEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;

removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;

}
```

I don't know how can change the `blobToFile()` function in order to preserve the recording quality during conversion. If you can help me with this, I would appreciate very much.

Comment: Have you setted a proper bit/sample frequency rate?

Comment: Not sure for the quality, but it is probably not a wav file you have here. No implementation of MediaRecorder I know of does record as wav, and if they did that wouldn't be here that you'd set it, but before you start the recorder. So what you have is an opus oga/webm-audio file.

Comment: I edited my post to show where I declared `MediaRecorder`.  Indeed, the file I obtain is `webm`.

Answer (score 8):

As I can see in the metadatas of the file you've [linked](https://www.get-metadata.com/result/10525caf-9757-4b4d-910e-abf60b62655b) in the comment.
You use a codec (here Opus) that compresses the file.

I see two solutions:

- Reduce the compressing ratio of the codec if you can.
- Use `WAV` container with an uncompressed configuration (for example PCM)

as you described me the problem in the chat I think it's more of the second solution.
I don't use mediarecorder myself but I've found this method to check if a mime type works with it.

```
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/wav;codecs=MS_PCM")
```

then you I suggest you change the mime type when creating the `Blob` to

```
new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM' });
```

or

```
new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/wav; codecs=0' });
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't set it anywhere. But as I can see from the detailed information provided here https://www.get-metadata.com/result/10525caf-9757-4b4d-910e-abf60b62655b, the Audio Sample Rate is 48000Hz and Audio Bits Per Sample is 32

Comment: Actually, the detailed analysis provided here https://www.get-metadata.com/result/10525caf-9757-4b4d-910e-abf60b62655b is identifying that the Audio Bits Per Sample is 32 and, still for Streams, the Bits Per Sample is 0. I think the problem is here.

Comment: Yes, I did. They sound well. Listen to it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zMGkgkA5EW7iCYSL7Kv7mePnEpMokJ0N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have an initial audio file. I just record my voice. Based on the recording I get a blob and based on the blob, I generate the audio file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178763/discussion-between-jsmith-and-emanuela-colta).

Comment: not yet. I am considering switching from `MediaRecorder` to `Recorder.js`

Comment: I am opening it now